# Can not perform POST requests to WooCommerce API

Tags: woocommerce, woothemes

I am struggling to get my POSTs working with the Woo Commerce API (v3).

Looking into the code, I found that POST requests run through this function `perform_oauth_authentication` (file class-wc-api-authentication.php line 135) which by default gets the authorization parameters from `$params = WC()->api->server->params['GET'];` which returns an empty array (makes sense as this is a POST request)

How do I get my post requests to properly hit the woo API with the right parameters? I am hesitating to include the authorization data in the query string  as my requests are done in HTTP

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Woocommerce API

**Authorization**

In Woocommerce API, authorization information is passed as URL params. In a non SSL HTTP request, the authorization data is encrypted and signed following OAuth standards.

**Client Library**

Alternatively, you can use a [client library](https://github.com/kloon/WooCommerce-REST-API-Client-Library) to make things much simpler. All you have to do is plugin the secret and key.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your quick response. So having the authorization data as part of the query string should be safe?

Comment: Yes, according to OAuth standards used